# Dynamically assign rowClasses attribute on <apex:dataTable> component

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a VisualForce page that renders into a PDF file with the following component declaration:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!someSObjectList}" var="SObj"
  rowClasses="{!IF( MOD( pos, 2 ) == 0, "grey_box,white_box", "white_box,grey_box" )}">
  .
  .  [column declarations]
  .
</apex:dataTable>
```

However, I cannot get it to compile. Attempting to save prompts the following error message:

> Save error: The element type "apex:dataTable" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:dataTable>".

How can I accomplish this (i.e. get zebra patterning with context-dependant first colour)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem is I was using double quotations to define the classes. This is awkward, once single class definitions work just fine.

Anyway, swaping the double quotes inside the IF clausule for single quotes seems to fix the problem, as indicated by @doug-b in SF StackExchange page.

Comment: Hi Andre, I am working on a similar stuff. I saw you are using 'pos' when calculates the rowClass. However, when I use the same 'pos' variable, apex complains that 'pos' does not exist in the controller. Do you set 'pos' anywhere inside your page?

Comment: @ShinyaKoizumi I declared an <apex:variable var="pos" value="{!0}"/> tag. Then you can update its value (tough unadviced by Salesforce) from inside an <apex:repeat> tag;